# I can't figure out what is causing this gap between the bottom of my content and the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

A copy of my page can be found [here](http://escapistdesign.com/sandbox/numbers.html).

I cannot figure out what css or html could be causing the 10-15 pixel gap that can be seen between the footer banner image and the end of the page. This is based on the WordPress theme twentytwelve.

Comment: this is because of scripts in bottom when I remove all scripts from bottom it works fine... so there is some issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed it for me! It's the 2 span.statcounter's towards the end of the page that are pushing it down.

```
.statcounter {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Of all the things it could've been... Thanks a lot! I've been trying to fix it for like two hours and that never even occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

there is two `<span>` after footer with `16px` height. you can use this code to remove that space:

```
.statcounter {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Looks like someone beat you to it 2 seconds earlier, but thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

reason of this issue is javascripts below footer, put javascripts between `<footer> and </body>` into a `<div>` with `0height, 0margin, 0padding, overflow:hidden;`